# Reading user input: No value entered v one value entered

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, computer-science

I'm having an issue with one of my methods:

```
public static int readIntoArray(Scanner input, int[] nums) {
    int i = 0; 
    int count = 0; //Will hold the number of values in array

    if (input.hasNextInt() == false) {
        count = 0;
    }

    else{
        int num = input.nextInt();

        do {
            nums[i] = num;
            i++;
            count++;
            num = input.nextInt();
            if (input.hasNextInt() == false) {
                nums[i] = num;
                count++;
            }
            else {

            }
        } while(input.hasNextInt() && i < 100);
    }

    return count;
}
```

This is one method in my program. My problem before was that I would get an error if the user hit enter without entering any values. I fixed that by creating the if-else statement in my code above.

But since that is the beginning part of the method I get an error when the user enters only one value. I'm not sure how to fix this because if I move the first if statement then I'll get an error when the user enters no values. I'm confused as to how to get this to play nice with the two different scenarios.

Basically the method, as it is above, won't work when the user enters one value.

Comment: *psst*, https://youtu.be/0Brn4YF_LY4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead; it's much more simple:

```
public static int readIntoArray(Scanner input, int[] nums) {
    
    int count = 0; // Will hold the number of values in array

    while(input.hasNextInt() && count < 100) {
        nums[count] = input.NextInt();
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Assume you only have one value in the input. Your code breaks because right after you increment `count`, you set `num` to the next int (which doesn't exist):

```
num = input.nextInt(); // there isn't a next int!
```

Also, I think the logic is off in the `if` loop in the `do while`. Pretend you have one input `3`, and we've resolved the single-input error. Right before the second `if` statement:

- `i` is 1.
- `count` is 1.
- `nums[0]` is 3.

  Next, `if (input.hasNextInt() == false)` will evaluate to true because `3` was our only input. Then:
- `i` is still 1.
- `count` is now 2.
- `nums[1]` is 3.

I'm almost certain this isn't what you want to happen.

Comment: Oh I see what I did. This is the first time I've used the input.hasNextInt() method so I wasn't completely sure how to implement it. And well now it makes sense comparing the code. Thank you!